# How can I identify the basic error in my clock webpage?

Tags: javascript, debugging, google-chrome

I am working on a clock which follows an ancient timekeeping at http://ancient-clock.stornge.com.

Right now Chrome has reported an error, but I'm not sure where it's coming from; Chrome says it cannot call a method on undefined, and the error message, in an HTML file containing JavaScript, is not near a line of JavaScript.

How do I identify the root cause when Chrome's debugger is not terribly helpful?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image]

It's at line 20. You have to set a breakpoint to trace where the problem is at. You can even view/change all the variables in the right panel.

[image]

As you can see, `summer_solstice` is not defined.

Comment: Is that line 20 starting after the opening SCRIPT tag?

Comment: @JonathanHayward - Line 20 in `js/clock.js`.

Answer (score 1):

Currently you are getting an error on the call to `ANCIENT_CLOCK.summer_solstice.getTime()` as `ANCIENT_CLOCK.summer_solstice` is not defined anywhere.

You do not have ANCIENT_CLOCK.summer_solstice or ANCIENT_CLOCK.winter_solstice defined.

And you are calling getTime() on both of these inside your ANCIENT_CLOCK.prepare_time function.